# avoid sql insert between times

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to avoid multiple sql inserts in a database. The idea is to wait at least 5 minutes before inserting again.

Getting time from last insert using

```
$query ="SELECT fecha
FROM almacen
WHERE fecha > NOW() - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1"

$espera=mysqli_query($conexion, $query)

if (empty($espera)) { inserting code } else { close }
```

But the query returns nothing when it should be returning a value. I was thinking it might be a problem since date was inserted using php `date ( "j/n/Y h:i");`

Should i change the time format? what should i use?

Comment: you should be using the default mysql date syntax when storing a date. The field should also be one of mysql's date types as well. If you want it to display another way use your application to do so and not mysql.

Comment: I agree. If wanting to return the data at any point you can use a function to display it how you want.

Comment: Please mention the exact data type of the column, and the line of PHP code with which you insert the values.

Comment: show us the almacen table structure and some example data. Are you also sure that there is an entry that match your requirement?

Comment: After reading comments, data type is datetime and now() sql fuction stores correctly. A weird problem im having is that if i use this code `<php if (empty($espera)) { ?> <p>empty</p>
 <?php } else {  ?>
<p>no empty</p>
  <?php } ?>` the no empty is displayed but if i run the sql query in phpmyadmin, it shows empty.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to restrict your rows to only 1 entry per 5 minutes I would:

Create a column called `insert_interval DATE` and create a unique index on that column. Then just attempt your insert, setting the value of insert_interval to 
whatever 5 minute interval the insert time falls under.

E.G. Normalize date to 5 minute interval.

```
select now() - interval (mod(minute(now()),5)) minute - interval second(now()) second;
```

Insert

```
insert into table(columns ..., insert_interval) values(
..., now() - interval mod(minute(now()),5) minute - interval second(now())
);
```

Only 1 row is allowed per 5 minute interval starting on the hour. So 1 row from 00:00:00 - 00:04:59, and so on. Any attempt to insert another row in that time window, would result in a duplicate key error, that you can catch and take appropriate action.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b887c/1)

*Uncomment the last insert to see the error on build schema.*